# How to use cURL requests with Swift URLSession

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I have a request that looks like this:

```
curl --header "token: YOUR TOKEN HERE" --data "a=new_session" site url
```

I understand and can use it via Terminal but I'm trying to do it with Swift and having some issues understanding how to pass parameters and make a request.

What I've tried:

```
guard let url = URL(string: siteURL) else { return }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "token")
        request.addValue("new_session", forHTTPHeaderField: "a")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else { print(error!.localizedDescription); return }
            guard let data = data else { print("Empty data"); return }

            if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print(str)
            }
       }.resume()
```

And that doesn't seem to work, I'm a very new to all this networking stuff and I don't even know why we pass token after ":" and new_session after "=" so I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're solution is almost correct. You're just incorrectly converting the `--data` flag from the curl request. The format of your data is form encoded because it has the format of `key=value`. So you just need to add the form encoded data (in this case `a=new_session`) to the body of your HTTP request instead of as a header. Also, make sure to set the proper content type.

It would look something like this:

```
func makeRequest(siteURL: String, token: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: siteURL) else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "token")

    // These two lines are what you were missing.
    request.httpBody = "a=new_session".data(using: .utf8)!
    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        // handle the request
    }.resume()
}
```

The `URLSession` request and `curl` request should be equivalent now.